# Unable to Parse the json object values inside the Ajax call Error section

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following Ajax call to a rest web API:-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/********/getbytitle('****')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
    
            if(data.d != null){

    //code goes here..

}
        
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.error.message.value);
        
        $("#customloader").hide();
    }
});
```

where inside the `error` section, i want to capture the error message value using  `alert(data.error.message.value);`, but i am getting the following error inside my browser console:-

```
data.error.message.value is undefined!!
```

although the JSON object have the following format:-

[image]

now as mentioned on the above picture, the error is returned if the user is not authorized. and our application will show username/password dialog box , when an unauthorized request is being received.. but i want to show the alert beside the username/pasword dialog box, with the json error message inside it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the first argument to the `error` handler is the XHR object, not the parsed JSON response.

To make this work as you require you need to get the `responseText` from the XHR yourself and parse it manually before attempting to read the `value` property. Try this:

```
error: function(xhr) {
  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(data.error.message.value);

  $("#customloader").hide();
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help